# NSScanner scan a string from end

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I have a filename like this WO.NO 193 AND TASK NO 15146.JPG. I want to split out the extension from the filename. Can someone tell how could i do this with NSSCanner, is there any other way than using the scanner. If so please let me know the solution.

Comment: you want to separate extension using scanner only no need altrnative method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods in `NSString` that do exactly that:

```
NSString *fn = @"WO.NO 193 AND TASK NO 15146.JPG";

NSString *basename = [fn stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSString *extension= [fn pathExtension];
```

So no need to use a scanner, unless you also have other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly is it correct way or not but it gives the correct value try once,

```
 NSString* str=@"WONO 193 AND TASK NO 15146.JPG";
    NSArray *array=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    str=[str substringToIndex:[str length]-([[array lastObject] length]+1)];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```